# Jest | test.each table | How to configure the test.each table with variables defined in beforeAll function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

How can I interpolate the `test.each` table with variables defined elsewhere? In the following example I am trying to use `someData` defined in `beforeAll`.
Here's the Jest functionality I am using: https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout

Follows a code snippet of what I am trying to do:

```js
const someCall = async () => {
  return { field: "lalala" };
};

describe(`Some test suite`, () => {
  let someData;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const callOutput = await someCall();
    someData = callOutput.field;
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {});

  it.each`
    data                | moreData
    ${{ name: "Jack" }} | ${"foo"}
    ${someData}         | ${"bar"}
  `("Tests here...", async ({ data, moreData }) => {
    console.log("Data:", data);                // <---- data is undefined for the second test
    console.log("More data:", moreData);
  });
});
```

The issue is that in the second test `someData` is `undefined` rather than having the value `"lalala"`.

Comment: You can't. All existing tests should be known at the time when test run starts. Proceed from this fact and use data somehow else.

Comment: Okay, then I guess a solution is to use the table literals as "pointers" to specific data, produced by logic written in `beforeAll`, needed for each test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the doc [Defining Tests](https://jestjs.io/docs/troubleshooting#defining-tests) says:

> Tests must be defined synchronously for Jest to be able to collect your tests.

> Note: This means when you are using test.each you cannot set the table asynchronously within a beforeEach / beforeAll.

Suggestion: You should prepare the test data before defining the test suites and test cases. Generate a `data.json` file use Node.js script or shell script, etc... Require and use the `data.json` file from your test file before running the `npm test` script.